# How do I embed a view as a form field and pass the information on

Tags: views, forms

I have a view that lists a number of nodes with images, I would like to take a grid view version of this and utilize it as a form. When the user clicks on an image, it will act like a selection box. Then, when the form is submitted that information will be passed on. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this with `hook_form_alter()` `and views_embed_view` you can also add html to a form this way.

```
function mymod_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

if ($form_id == 'your_form_id') {

       $form['what do you want'] = array(
         '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#title' => t('Question'),
         '#description' => t('Here is a question ?'),
         '#default_value' => $form['#node']->something ? $form['#node']->something : 'itis',
         '#required' => FALSE,
         '#suffix' => '<div>html test here</div>',
         '#weight' => 0,
       );

       $form['contact_information'] = array(
         '#value' => "<div>some html</div>",
       );

       $form['choose_an_image'] = array(
         '#value' => views_embed_view('my_image_view', $display_id = 'default'),
         '#weight' => 0,
       );

      return $form;
   }

}
```